# How to pass this parameter to custom ReactJS component when redirecting/routing?

Tags: reactjs

So the goal is this: we want a button called "X type management" to be in the admin sidebar. When an admin clicks on it, the app will take him to a (common) page "TypeManagement" component. This is needed because I want to use the 1 component for 3 "TypeManagements", for X, Y and Z. So, my idea was to pass a parameter "X" as string so that in the TypeManagement component I could get the correct data based on parameter that was passed.

App.js :

```
      ...
         <GuardedRoute
            path="/assettypebeheer"
            component={TypeManagementIndex}
            canAccess={true}
            kindOfType={"asset"}
          />
     </Switch>
```

GuardRoute.js (class component) :

```
render() {
const accesWithoutLogin = this.props.canAccess;
const rest = this.props.rest;
const Component = this.props.component;
const componentPermission = this.props.permission;
const permissions = usePermissionState();
const kindOfType = this.props.kindOfType;

if (permissions != null) {
  const hasAuthority = this.checkPermissions(
    permissions,
    componentPermission
  );

  if (kindOfType) {
    return (
      <SpecificTypeRoute
        component={Component}
        hasAuthority={hasAuthority}
        kindOfType={kindOfType}
      />
    );
  } else {
  ...

  ...
  const SpecificTypeRoute = ({
     component: Component,
     kindOfType,
     hasAuthority,
     ...rest
   }) => (
  <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
         hasAuthority === true ? (
         <Component {...props} kindOfType={kindOfType} />
       ) : (
         <Redirect to="/scanner" />
       )
     }
  />
 );

export default GuardedRoute;
```

So the logic here is that in my App.js I pass the "kindOfType" parameter, which in my example would be a string "X". This enters my GuardRoute component, in which the constant "const kindOfType" is filled in! Great!

Since kindOfType is filled in, we will enter the "if-clause", and a SpecificTypeRouteComponent is created & redirected to. This is done in my defined constant at the bottom of my file, seen here above. I want to pass the component, hasAuthority and kindOfType parameters. When having a breakpoint in my SpecificTypeRoute constant, I see the values are passed, but then when rendering the "hasAuthority = true" path, I.e. my custom component that should handle X, Y and Z, the "kindOfType" parameter is not passed. When logging the props in my new component, "kindOfType: undefined" is shown.

Does anyone know how I can pass the string "X" in this way? Is this THE way to do it? Is there a better way? Should I make different X, Y and Z components even though they're almost identical (in setup/display)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `to` as abject with state. Here is link to doc https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect/to-object